# Tables not getting created in Postgresql using Gorm

Tags: go-gorm

I am trying to create a table from a struct using the following code. It had initially worked by hard coding the credentials to test. Once changing to env vars, I wanted to test that the tables and schemas would get created as expected.

So far I have tried:

1. Removing the tables from the db, running "go run main.go".

   - Result: Established connection successfully to the db, but tables do not get created.
2. Deleting the database, recreating the database using psql "CREATE DATABASE" command, and running "go run main.go"

   - Result: Established connection successfully to the db, but tables do not get created.
3. Use AutoMigrate, but was not able to successfully create the tables.
4. Debug: When I run it in debug mode, the debug console displays that its connected, i see no indication of any errors. I have not been coding for many years, still in the learning process.

Below are 2 files, main.go and api.go (opens db)

MAIN.GO

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "gitlab......"
    _ "gitlab....."
)

var err error

func main() {

api := controllers.API{}

// Using env vars from a config file
api.Initialize("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable")

// BIND TO A PORT AND PASS OUR ROUTER IN
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handlers.CORS()(api.Router)))

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

// Models
type Application struct {
    ID        string    `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Ci        string    `json:"ci"`

// CREATE TABLES AND SCHEMA IF TABLES DO NOT EXIST
if !api.Database.HasTable(&Application{}) {
    api.Database.CreateTable(&Application{})
    }
```

API.GO

```
func (api *API) Initialize(opts string) {

// Initialize DB
dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable",
    config.DB_USER, config.DB_PASSWORD, config.DB_NAME, config.PORT)
api.Database, err = gorm.Open("postgres", dbinfo)

if err != nil {
    log.Print("failed to connect to the database")
    log.Fatal(err)

}

fmt.Println("Connection established")
log.Printf("Postgres started at %s PORT", config.PORT)
}
```

I have already created the database, and am able to establish a connection to the database. Just can not get the tables created.

Ideas?

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. Have you tested your code to make sure the statements you think are being run are being run? Are you even reaching the CreateTable statement? What is the typical manner you would handle the case where a function would fail?

Comment: @ jdv, lol -> SO is a terrible debugger, i aggree.I would usually use breakpoints to make sure that portion of the code is hit. The

Comment: *Accidently hit enter too soon*. I would usually use breakpoints to make sure that portion of the code is reached. When i run it in debug mode, the debug console displays that its connected, i see no indication of any errors. I have not been doing this for so long, this I am learning.

Comment: (You should put details like this in the text of the question.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill remember that next time.

Comment: Added it to the original text of the question.

Comment: Please, remember to check `api.Database.CreateTable(&Application{}).Error`. To debug efficiently, also add `api.Database.LogMode(true)` so you can see what's actually executed. See http://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html

Comment: Update...when I originally posted this question I was defining the structs inside other model files. Once I moved the structs in API.go, it created all the tables and schemas.

Comment: BUT, have still not successfully created the tables and schemas just from the models, without adding the structs inside API.go. And yes I have the package imported in the MAIN.go.